# Im stuck on a powershell script that has to compress all files from multiple subfolders to a destination folder

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

Im stuck on a Powershell script that has to compress all files recursively from multiple subfolders to a destination folder.

Something like this:

From:

```
c:\backup\user\documents\\*  
c:\backup\user2\\*  
c:\backup\new\program\\*
```

To:

```
x:\backupfolder\file1.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

According to PS documentation, you can use the function `Compress-Archive` to do this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6

```
$compress = @{
Path= "c:\backup\user\documents*", "c:\backup\user2*", "c:\backup\new\program*"
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = "x:\backupfolder\file1.zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress
```

Comment: How can i zip it using 7zip. I dont need this using compress-Archive function